# How to add all edited files in gitbash command prompt?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, bitbucket

I'm new to [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/dashboard/overview), when I want to push something to master branch, I do this:

```
git add test.html
git commit -m "messsage"
git push
```

My question is, is there a way to do `git add` but target all files that you edited? I don't want to manually type them in everytime. And what if I forgot which files I changed...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git add -A` will add all files to the staged area

then you can do `git commit -m 'message'` and `git push`

what `git add -A` does is,

it will find new files as well as staging modified content and removing files that are no longer in the working tree. as in [its manual.](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-add.html)

Comment: so I just do this:
`git add -A`
`git commit -m "messsage"`
`git push`
?

Comment: does git `add -A`, add all files or only the ones that u changed?

Comment: `git add -A` adds (and removes) all the files, `git add -u` only the ones that changes.

Comment: `git add -A .` is more proper, as the behavior of `git add -A` will change in Git 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

git add -A will add the modified files and new ( untracked files ) to staging except that the new files are not mentioned in .gitignore.

For ex:

.gitignore file contains

*.sh

touch a.sh b.sh 1.pl

git add -A # Adds only 1.pl file to staging.